# Codeigniter phpActiveRecord Create error

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
pubic static $primary_key = 'userId';
private function isUserLoggedIn() {}

}
```

The error I get:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: lib/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 830

Comment: Are you using the github version? If not which one.

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with your problem, but anyway: as column names aren't case-sensitive in SQL but `phpactiverecord` does force them to be lower-case, so you'd probably be better of putting `userid` in as your primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a few months late, but I'm just getting into php-activerecord myself.

Your problem might be that you typed "pubic" instead of "public", and php by default doesn't support any pubic variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is going to be in your Users model.  It's possible you didn't extend CI_Model, you didn't call parent::construct() in the users constructor, or there is some other error in there.

Comment: It has something to do with me specifying the $primary_key any idea why this is?

Comment: You're going to need to post more code.  You didn't post any of the actual active record code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to absence of **auto-increment** field in your table.
Please add **auto-increment** field.

I had faced the same issue.